# Subjunctive Protasis and Aorist Indicative Apodosis

Tags: ancient-greek, conditions, aorist

> ἐὰν μή τις **μένῃ** ἐν ἐμοί, **ἐβλήθη** ἔξω ὡς τὸ κλῆμα ... (John 15:6)

**μένῃ** is *present subjunctive* and **ἐβλήθη** is *aorist indicative*. In many grammar books, there are two types of conditional sentence which begin with a *subjunctive* verb:

(1)

PRESENT GENERAL CONDITIONAL SENTENCE

Protasis: ἐὰν + subjunctive

Apodosis: present indicative

(2)

FUTURE MORE VIVID CONDITIONAL SENTENCE

Protasis: ἐὰν + subjunctive

Apodosis: future indicative

In John 15:6, the apodosis is aorist indicative. To which type of conditional sentence does this structure belong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still a present general conditional. You might have noticed in some grammars that they will say for the present general apodosis, it takes the "present indicative or an equivalent." The aorist is the equivalent here, and functions as a gnomic aorist.

See Smyth § 2338:

> 2338. The **gnomic aorist** is equivalent to the present indicative in apodosis.
>       *ἢν δέ τις τούτων τι παραβαίνῃ, ζημίαν αὐτοῖς ἐπέθεσαν  but if any one* ever *transgresses any one of these regulations, they* always *impose punishment upon them (him)* X. C. 1.2.2.

You can do the same for John 15.6:

> If anyone does not remain in me, they are cast out like a twig.